# Execute PowerShell script on remote server after Thycotic Secret Server password change

Tags: powershell, secret-server

We're running the Thycotic Secret Server platform and attempting to onboard a secret associated with a Windows Service account. When Secret Server updates the password, I want a PowerShell to run on a remote server (i.e. the Windows Service host). From what I can tell, it appears that the PowerShell script is only running on the Secret Server, no matter what I put in the "Machine Name" field. See below:

[image]

I know this is the case, because within the script I am trying to access local files on `remote_server_name.my.domain`, but getting "File Does not Exist" errors. E.g. `c:\Program Files\Some_Directory\FileName.txt`. The only way I can access the file is by using a full FQDN path, i.e. `\\remote_server_name.my.domain\c$\Program Files\Some_Directory\FileName.txt`.

Below is the PowerShell script I am trying to get Secret Server to run on `remote_server_name.my.domain` run:

```
$appset = "c:\Program Files\Some_Directory\FileName.txt"
$a = Get-Content $appset | ConvertFrom-Json;

$a.'example'.node.password = $Args[0];

$a | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content $appset;
Restart-Service -Name "service_name"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Invoke-Command will do it but you need proper permissions, network ports and services started on the remote host.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to tinker with what the right index of $args should be, but something like this should work:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $args[0] -ArgumentList $args[1] {
    param($password)
    $appset = 'c:\Program Files\Some_Directory\FileName.txt'
    $a = Get-Content $appset | ConvertFrom-Json
    $a.example.node.password = $password
    $a | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content $appset
    Restart-Service -Name "service_name"
}
```

As you get further into making scripts like this you'll probably want to parameterize more of these values. For example, you'll probably want $appset and service_name to be parameters you can set via the UI.

When you add those values as parameters, you'll interact with them via $args rather than hard code them in your script, but $args is also used inside invoke-command, so you'll need to be aware of scoping.

Answer (score 1):

The "Creating and Using PowerShell Scripts" section of their [documentation for 11.6.x](https://docs.delinea.com/online-help/secret-server/api-scripting/configuring-winrm-powershell/index.htm) says

> At the moment, we only support running PowerShell scripts on localhost

It looks like the "Machine Name" field only gets used by some other dependency types like Remote File dependencies. For "Powershell Script" type dependencies, the [full admin guide](https://docs.delinea.com/online-help/pdf-secret-server/delinea-secret-server.pdf) says:

> In the Edit Dependency dialog, enter `default` in the **Machine Name** field.

Though you can probably put anything, as you've seen already.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response @Cpt.Whale. Within the documentation you linked is an example of rotating the password of an AD user used to run a SQL Server instance. In the example, PowerShell Remote Commands are being used. I will assume (and admittedly, it makes sense that) this is what Thycotic wants you to do:

[image]